# Using jsp:include to pass a array from one jsp page to another

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

In my spring application, for each entity class, I have a set of views which share a common structure. the common structure is store in a separate jsp file placed in /WEB-INF/jsp/common. the specific jsp page are store in /WEB-INF/jsp/private/ and right now have this content:

```
<jsp:include page="../../common/listagem.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="entity" value="<Entity_name>"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Besides the param `entity`, I need pass to the common jsp page a array with the atributes of the entity. I was using something like this:

```
<jsp:param name="elements" value="login"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="pnome"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="unome"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="email"/>
```

but I wanted something like this:

```
<jsp:param name="elements" value="login,pnome,unome,email"/>
```

Also, in the super class for my entity classes, I have this method:

```
public List<String> getListaArgumentos() {
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    int counter = 0;
    String nome = this.getArgumentName(counter);
    do {
        lista.add(nome);
        nome = this.getArgumentName(++counter);
    }while(nome != null);

    return lista;
}
```

which return a list of the atributes names. If I pass from my constructor this list to my view, Is there a way to use this to replace `"login,pnome,unome,email"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this new value into the ModelAndView in your controller

```
           ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("your view");
           mav.addObject("arguments",getListaArgumentos());
```

Then you can pass in the view to common like this before make the include

```
        <c:set var="arguments" value="${arguments}" scope="request"/>

        <jsp:include page="../../common/listagem.jsp">
```

By the way, never use you own language to coding, remember than the biggest community of developer are anglo speaker.